# Angular 2 : How to pass function into child component

Tags: angular

In an Angular 2 app, say i have a 'SaveComponent' where clicking its save button calls a function `isDirty()` that returns true or false (true if the content of the parent component has been modified). Note the reason for the 'SaveComponent' is that it has styles and other 'widgets' associated with it that are shared among many components.

currently there is a `isDirty` function defined in each of the parent components, and the function is passed to `SaveComponent` as follows inside the parent template:

```
<save-component [isDirty]="isDirty"> </save-component>
```

if you care to see, a simplified version of `SaveComponent` is defined something like this...

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'save-component',
  templateUrl: 'who-cares-to-know.component.html'
})

export class SaveComponent {
  @Input() isDirty;
}
```

It works *only* initially. It seems that the `isDirty` function only returns `false` (or only called once?) even when the content is modified. Note that the function does work correctly when it's called from the parent component.

What's wrong? Is it possible to pass function from parent to child component via `@Input` or some other means? Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing `[(ngModel)]="isDirty"` on a textbox or something to update your value? (On the parent component that is)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you lose the context of your method when referencing  it, i.e. the "this" keyword.

I would use something like that:

```
getIsDirty() {
  return () => {
    return this.isDirty();
  }
}
```

With the arrow function, you will be able to use the lexical this. The latter corresponds to the component instance itself.

And provide it to the sub component this way:

```
<save-component [isDirty]="getIsDirty()"> </save-component>
```

Comment: It seems this returns the function itself in the Child component, does anything have to be done there for the `@Input() isDirty` ?

Comment: to run the function in child component treat `@Input isDirty` as function instead of property. Call  `this.isDirty()` instead of just `this.isDirty`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but I just ran into the issue so hopefully this can help someone moving forward. I also tried to edit the first answer but that was rejected, and I don't have enough reputation to comment on the first answer.

The first answer is correct, but it's not complete. In order to call the parent function in the child component you need to treat `@Input() isDirty` as a function as opposed to a property.

Call `this.isDirty()` as opposed to `this.isDirty` in order to run the function.